# Iterator returned by std::max_element(vList.begin(), vList.end()) changes value after clearing and updating the vector(vList)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iterator

For a BucketSort program using a vector of lists. I used std::max_element to find out the maximum element from the vector.

But it looks like once the original vector is cleared and updated, the iterator returned by max_element also changes the value to the updated value from vector (vList) from same index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void BucketSort(std::vector<int>& vList)
{
    int i = 0;

    auto maxElem = std::max_element(vList.begin(), vList.end());
    std::vector<std::list<int>> tempList;
    std::cout << "Max element = " << *maxElem << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i <= *maxElem; i++)
        tempList.push_back({});

    for (auto x : vList)
    {
        tempList[x].push_back(x);
    }

    vList.clear();
    std::cout << "*max = " << *maxElem << "\n";
    i = 0;
    while(i <= *maxElem)
    {
        std::cout << "*max = " << *maxElem << " i = " << i << " tempList[i].size() = " << tempList[i].size() << "\n";
        if (tempList[i].empty() == false)
        {
            vList.push_back(tempList[i].front());
            tempList[i].pop_front();
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vList = {1, 5, 4, 1 };
    BucketSort(vList);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces below output

```
Max element = 5
*max = 5
*max = 5 i = 0 tempList[i].size() = 0
*max = 5 i = 1 tempList[i].size() = 2
*max = 5 i = 1 tempList[i].size() = 1
*max = 1 i = 1 tempList[i].size() = 0
```

Does the iterator retain the reference to the index returned even after clearing the vector?

Comment: What makes you think that an iterator to a deleted element would continue to work? Why store an iterator and not value it points to?

Comment: If I try to change the position of 5 (maximum element) in the vector, then the last loop iteration count also changes.
e.g. in the current vector value, {1, 5, 4, 1 },  when I print the vList after BucketSort() call, it prints 1, 1. But if I modify the vector to {1, 4, 5, 1}, then final vList contents become 1, 1, 4.

Comment: Clearing a vector, and growing a vector beyond its capacity, will invalidate any active iterators to its elements. See [Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/)

Comment: @Uddesh `vList.clear();` -- The vector's contents are gone -- so what do you think the iterator `maxElem` is pointing to?

Comment: *when I print the vList after BucketSort() call, it prints 1, 1. But if I modify the vector to {1, 4, 5, 1}, then final vList contents become 1, 1, 4* -- All you're really doing is playing games with undefined behavior.  The iterator has been invalidated -- trying to "figure out" what happens when you access an iterator that has been invalidated is pointless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Remy Lebeau, Yes, I also had the same understanding/thought, that the iterator will become invalid and would cause undefined behavior once the vector is cleared. But since changing the max element position produced results in the same pattern (tried with visual studio as well as online c++ compilers), I got some doubt if the iterator retains the reference to the memory position of the vector and will still hold the updated value.

Comment: It's [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) regardless of what actual results you happen to observe. The program is invalid and *anything* can happen - you have *no* guarantee of *any* specific behaviour.

Comment: @Uddesh *tried with visual studio* -- Using Visual Studio 2019, this line: `std::cout << "*max = " << *maxElem << "\n"` -- stops with an invalid memory access when run with the debug runtime.  There is nothing to print, since the program stops dead right there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I was using Visual Studio 2022 with Release mode. With debug mode it does crash. Thanks for suggesting the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterators provided in C++ store an address that is referenced. When you clear the vector and fill it with new values, the iterator is still pointing to the same place and will show the new value in that location. Take a look at this example:

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
     ^
```

You have an iterator pointing to the third element of the vector. Now imagine you clear the vector and fill it with new values:

```
[5,6,7,8,9]
     ^
```

Now the pointer points to the same address, but that memory now holds a new value. You can get around this by storing the data in a local variable and use it throughout the rest of your code:
`int maxValue = *maxElem`